# Generate a Unique Page with the details after a form submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form, where the user can fill in his name, email, address, phone, age and they can also order something like a product.

After submitting the form, all information will be stored in a database & also `phpmail` will send an email with all the information.

But after the submit, I want the user to see this :

```
This is your details: http://example.com/order.php?unique=21434612
```

On clicking link, they will see a page with all the information they had filled in the form. Like this :

```
Your name is : $name

Your age is: $age

etc.
```

So how can I generate auto HTML pages after submit?

Comment: Why not just have a generic page that fetches the order tails in the database out from the ID provided?

Comment: Have you got any code that you have tried so far? That way, we can point you in the right direction!

Comment: Yes i have but my form is tooo long to post here..

Comment: I just have a form if they submit, i want that a unquie secrect page will be created for the user, where he always can see his filled details ONLINE

Comment: @Epodax Yes i know how to ouput the data;s but how can i create a unique page for each user?

Comment: That's my point, why not just create a file called orderdetails.php and call that with the user / order ID, and then on that page fetch the details?

Comment: @Epodax Because that is not secure i tink... if somewone will get this: `orderdetails.php?id=25` and he will change the id in `orderdetials.php?id=27` , he can see the details from a another user..

Comment: Then add some security, store the ID in a SESSION or cookie?

Comment: @Epodax Hmm you talk so easy :P Nice.. But do you maybe have a example for me? I will appreciate that!

Comment: Google php $_SESSION and(/or) setcookie, a simple way to do it would be to place the following at the "last page" of the order process: `session_start(); $_SESSION['orderID'] = $orderID;` and then on the page you want to get the details you do `$orderID = $_SESSION['orderID'];`

Comment: @Epodax Thanks i gonna try it now, Hope that i can fix it.. it will take me some days to fix it i think.. because my php is not so strong.. but anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

write this code on the page where you want the detail.configure your details. like dbname and row details etc. yes this data is printed in table format. if you dont like it just remove it.

.

```
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", " ") or die (mysqli_error   ());

        // Select database
      mysqli_select_db($con,"rdb") or die(mysqli_error());

     // SQL query
     $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tablename";

     // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
     $rs = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);

    print "
   <table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"border-     collapse: collapse\" bordercolor=\"#808080\" width=\"100&#37;\"    id=\"AutoNumber2\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">
  <tr>
  <td width=100>ID:</td> 
  <td width=100>First Name</td> 
  <td width=100>Last Name</td> 
  <td width=100>Email</td> 
  <td width=100>User Name</td>
  <td width=100>Password</td> 
  <td width=100>Date Of Birth</td> 
  <td width=100>Gender</td> 
   </tr>"; 
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
   { 
  print "<tr>"; 
  print "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; 
   print "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>"; 
   print "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>"; 
   print "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
   print "<td>" . $row['uname'] . "</td>";
   print "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
   print "<td>" . $row['dob'] . "</td>";
   print "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>"; 
   print "</tr>"; 
   } 
   print "</table>"; 

  }
 }
```

Comment: I already know this, but how can i make a random page for that user? So that if they submit, they will get a unique link, where they can see their detail infos?

Comment: And that is just what i can not fix can you help me please? Add me on skype: missessalima , maybe we can talk there out.. Thanks